# How can I reset running total in SQL BigQuery after condition in other column is met?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, cumulative-sum

In BigQuery, I have a data set from Google Analytics on hit level containing, amongst others: `date`, `fullVisitorId`, `visitId`, `transactionRevenue`, and `pageHome` (whether or not the page someone is on is the homepage or not). For each visitor, I want to calculate the running total of `pageHome` *until a transaction is made*. If a transaction is made, then `transactionRevenue` is a number, otherwise it's null. For an example, please see the attached picture.

[Example table running total](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trkOM.png)

I have tried a sum over the partition by `fullVisitorId` and ordering by `visitId`. However, I'm not sure how to reset when `transactionId` is not null.

```
SELECT
    date,
    fullVisitorId,
    visitId,
    visitNumber,
    transactionRevenue,
    pageHome,
    SUM(pageHome) OVER(PARTITION BY fullVisitorId ORDER BY visitId ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS sumpageHome
```

This code calculates the running total per visitor, but it does not reset yet after a transaction is made.

Answer (score 2):

> For each visitor, I want to calculate the running total of pageHome until a transaction is made.

Use a subquery to calculate the transaction number.  Then use that in a cumulative sum:

```
SELECT SUM(pageHome) OVER (PARTITION BY fullVisitorId,  transaction_count ORDER BY DATE) as running_pageHome
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             COUNT(TransactionRevenue) OVER (PARTITION BY fullVisitorId ORDER BY DATE) as transaction_count
      FROM t
     ) t
```

Comment: Thanks, almost works! However, visits during which there is no transaction are added to the previous transaction. Any idea how to solve this?